# Cannot @Autowire a @Bean property

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a DAO class which is annotated with `@Configuration`. In this DAO class I have a bean defined as

```
@Bean
public MyDao myDao(){
    return new MyDao(dataSource);
}
```

Now I want to use this DAO in my service class. So I annotated the service class with `@Service` and used

```
@Autowired private IMyDao myDao;
```

While running the tests I get the below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [IMyDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Could you check whether the `myDao()` is actually called?

Comment: How are you loading the different configuration files?

Comment: There's not enough info here to tell exactly what the problem is. Does `MyDao` implement `IMyDao`? What does the complete DAO class look like? Is the DAO class included in component scanning? It sounds strange that you would but `@Configuration` on the DAO class itself instead of on a separate class.

Comment: @StanislavL What you mean?I believe If I annotate the class with Configuration spring will find the methods annotated with Bean and will create those ?

Comment: Annotate with @Configuration and let the package where the class placed be included in the package scan

Comment: @M.Deinum Initially the Service class was defined in the application context (xml) file and the test was working. I was trying to move the bean declaration from xml to Annotation. So I removed the bean definition from xml, annotated the service class (which has been removed frm xml) with `@Service` and used `@Autowired` for the dao.

Comment: @Jesper Yes MyDao implements IMyDao. The DAO class is included in the component scanning.
Initially the Service class was defined in the application context (xml) file and the test was working. I was trying to move the bean declaration from xml to Annotation. So I removed the bean definition from xml, annotated the service class (which has been removed frm xml) with `@Service` and used `@Autowired` for the dao.

There are several `@Bean` defined in the same DAO class

Comment: Are you able to load other beans defined in the same dao class?

Comment: @saurabhkumar no

Comment: use @configuration on DAO class

Comment: @LovaChittumuri I did

Comment: Good continue with coding

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application context

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="your top level package">
    <context:include-filter type="regex"
    expression="com\.your package\..*Dao.*" />
    <context:include-filter type="regex"
    expression="com\.your package\..*Service.*" />
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
    expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
```

Comment: He is using an `@Configuration` class for his DAO. What he actually should do is add this configuration class to the xml he is using (or include a component scan that detects that `@Configuration` class).

Comment: @M.Deinum that's what i mean by my answer.

Comment: Not according to what I see in your answer.... -> *name of package where u have defined MyDao* should refer to config not the dao.

Comment: that's correct right ,you pass the package name of your configuration class

Comment: Those includes don't add anything but complexity. The exclude depends on what your need is (if you have a single context you don't want to exclude anything).